# suppress first page header using css media print

Tags: css

How can i suppress/hide elements when printing especially a header at first page only.

```
<table>
   <thead><tr><td>must be invisible at first page</td><tr></thead>
   <tbody><tr><td>content></td></tr></tbody>
   <tfoot><tr><td>footer</td></tr></tfoot>
</table>
```

i have read [Remove Header from First Page of HTML Generated PDF - CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500871/remove-header-from-first-page-of-html-generated-pdf-css), which is seems to be solutions, but it has dead link.

and i dont understand bellow code:

```
@page {
        @top-center {
        content: element(header,first-except);
}
```

what is content: element(...) ?
where can i get manual/reference to this element (xxx) function ?

thx

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/#funcdef-element

Comment: I am currently facing the same problem, so if you have a solution, will you please be kind enough to share? Thanks