# CSS: remove @page footer on the first page

Tags: html, css, printing, footer

I have defined a HTML/CSS page for printing that utilize CSS @page features to define a header and a footer.

On the first page, I do not want a footer. Here [Remove Header from First Page of HTML Generated PDF - CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500871/remove-header-from-first-page-of-html-generated-pdf-css) it is described how I remove the footer in a sense of "not showing it". That works, but unfortunately, some space is still kind of reserved for the footer. When I want to place an element close to the end of the title page, it will not work, it will be wrapped to the next page.

[plenty of room that "some more content" could move down, but as soon as I add some margin-top it will be moved to the next page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtgwp.png)

In the following the minimal working example. I use Weasyprint to translate HTML/CSS into PDF.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>test</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="title_page.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header-left">
          some header left
        </div>
        <div class="header-right">
          some header right
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          
          <!-- Title page -->
          
          <div class="main-image-and-sub">
            some content
          </div>
          <div class="lower-detail-box">
            some more content
          </div>


          <!-- Sections -->
          <h2>Section 1</h2>
          <h2>Section 2</h2>
          <h2>Section 3</h2>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS: (the class lower-detail-box has the margin-top property. When you remove the comment, the element will me moved to the next page)

```
body {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  margin: 0px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@media print {
  h2 { 
    page-break-before: always;
  }
  h3, h4 {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
  pre, blockquote {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }

  html, body {
    width: 297mm;
    height: 210mm;
  }
}

@page  {
  size: A4 landscape;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;

  /*
   * Header
   */
  @top-left{
      content: element(header-left);
      /* margin-top: 27mm; */
  }

  @top-center{
    height: 90px;
  }

  @top-right{
      content: element(header-right);
      height: 90px;
  }


  /*
   * Footer
   */
  @bottom-right {
      content: element(footer-right);
      background-color: yellow;
      margin-top: 20px;
      padding-right: 34px;
      width: 450px;
      height: 50px;
  }

  @bottom-center{
      content: counter(page) ' / ' counter(pages);
      background-color: yellow;
      margin-top: 20px;
      font-family: 'Arial';
      color: white;
      width: 222px;
      height: 50px;
  }

  @bottom-left{
      content: string(heading);
      background-color: yellow;
      margin-top: 20px;
      padding-left: 35px;
      font-family: 'Arial';
      color: white;
      width: 450px;
      height: 50px;
  }
}

/* 
 * Title page, we remove the footer here
 */
 @page:first {
  @bottom-right {
    content: normal;
  }

  @bottom-center{
    content: normal;

  }

  @bottom-left{
    content: normal;
  }
}





/*
 * Header
 */
.header-left {
  position: running(header-left);
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.header-right {
  position: running(header-right);
  margin-right: 35px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


h2 { string-set: heading content() }

.footer-right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  position: running(footer-right);
}

.main-image-and-sub {
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 496px;
}


.lower-detail-box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;

  height: 111px;
  /* margin-top: 10px; */
  
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-right: 33px;

  background-color: lightblue;
}
```